# Google Javascript API - If statement within .each is breaking loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, google-maps-api-3

I am working with GMaps JS API3. I have JSON file with my location data in it.

I'm trying to:

1. Grab the location data from the JSON file (seems to be working fine)
2. Grab the bounds of the map (also seems to be working)
3. Render the markers for locations that are inside the bounds
4. Render listings corresponding to the markers that are inside the bounds.

The problem I'm having is that when the if statement:

```
if(bounds.contains(resPosition)) {...}
```

returns false at any point, the $.each loop that contains it just seems to stop looping through the rest of the results. I'm probably missing something stupid here, but can anyone give me some help diagnosing this?

```
function getLocationData() {

var markerIcon = {
  url: markerIconURI,
  size: new google.maps.Size(30,35),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30,35),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 35),
  labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15,13.5)
};

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: locationList,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        error: function() {
            console.log("Can't import location data.");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("ul.wm_section--dealer-locator__result-list").empty();
            markers = [];
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            var locationNumber = 1;

            $(data.location).each(function(key, value) {

                var markerLabel = parseFloat(value.id) + parseFloat(1); //add 1 to the object id
                var resPosition = {lat: parseFloat(value.lat), lng: parseFloat(value.lng)};

                if( bounds.contains(resPosition) ) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: {lat: parseFloat(value.lat), lng: parseFloat(value.lng)},
                        title: value.title,
                        markerID: value.id,
                        icon: markerIcon,
                        label: {
                            text: "0"+locationNumber,
                            color: "#000",
                            fontSize: "16px",
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                            fontFamily: "condiut-light,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
                            position: "relative",
                            top: "-5px"
                          }

                    }); //eo new marker


                    if (value.isPreferred === 'true') {
                        $("ul.wm_section--dealer-locator__result-list").append('<li id="marker-' + value.id + '" class="wm_card--dealer-locator masters-club"><h6 class="wm_card--dealer-locator__number">0' + locationNumber + '<h6 class="wm_card--dealer-locator__title">' + value.title + '</h6><p class="wm_card--dealer-locator__address">' + value.address + ', ' + value.city + ', ' + value.state + ', ' + value.zip + '</p><p class="wm_card--dealer-locator__phone">Call ' + value.phone + '</p><a class="wm_card--dealer-locator__button" href="#">Contact Me</a><img class="wm_masters-club-image" src="assets/images/masters.jpg"/></li>');
                        console.log("preferred fired");
                    } else {
                        $("ul.wm_section--dealer-locator__result-list").append('<li id="marker-' + value.id + '" class="wm_card--dealer-locator"><h6 class="wm_card--dealer-locator__number">0' + locationNumber + '<h6 class="wm_card--dealer-locator__title">' + value.title + '</h6><p class="wm_card--dealer-locator__address">' + value.address + ', ' + value.city + ', ' + value.state + ', ' + value.zip + '</p><p class="wm_card--dealer-locator__phone">Call ' + value.phone + '</p><a class="wm_card--dealer-locator__button" href="#">Contact Me</a></li>');
                        console.log("standard fired");
                    }
                    markers.push(marker); //push all markers into an array
                    console.log("markers: " + markers);
                }


                locationNumber++;
                highlighter(marker); //call ui interactivity

            }); // eo data.location each
        } // eo .ajax:success
    }); // eo .ajax
  }); // eo gmaps listener
} //eo getlocationdata()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess, since I don't see the code for `highlighter`, but I would imagine the issue is related to this:

```
if( bounds.contains(resPosition) ) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       // ...
     });
     // ...
}
highlighter(marker);
```

`marker` is getting [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the function, so then the `if` is `false`, when you do

```
highlighter(marker);
```

you are really doing

```
highlighter(undefined);
```

I would imagine that in that function, at some point it tries to access some property, and it is throwing an `Uncaught TypeError` or something along those lines.

I would first try moving `highlighter(marker)` inside of your `if` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yep... You are awesome. Not sure how I missed that. Thank you so much!!!